# How do I get a parent function to execute something every time it gets data from its subprocess?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

So assume I have two scripts: one is a xml-sax reader, the other is supposed to process the results of the parsing process.

My "playground" model for the parser looks like this:

```
import json

def generator():
    n=0
    while n < 100:
        data_package = {n:"test", 101:"some more info"}
        temp = json.dumps(data_package)
        print(temp)
        n = n + 1

generator()
```

It simulates the production of dicts by the parser, packs them into a json dump string to be sent to its parent function.

This parent function spawns the xml-reader as a subprocess, should take the dict and process the information further. Playground example:

```
import subprocess

child = subprocess.Popen(args=["python3", "playground-parser.py"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

What I'm missing now, is a way for the parser to tell the parent "hey I have finished another `data_package`, I wait while you handle it", the parent to receive this message, handle and discard the `data_package` and send a message to the child which tells it that it can proceed and send another `data_package`.

What I think I've gathered from reading other subprocess questions on stackoverflow:

- I need to put the stdout of the xml-parser script into a pipe, so the parent gets it as soon as it's available.
- I can use `Popen.communicate()` to send text to the child? I can't wrap my head around what it actually communicates though as it's also used to access the collected outputs and errors of the child from the parent (`outs, errors = child.communicate()`)
- There is a `Popen.send_signal()`, the docs only say "Sends the signal signal to the child." and continue to talk about sending exit or terminate signals.

I can't piece together how I'm able to communicate from the child to the parent and have it actually listen and execute when it receives information from the child.

Thanks in advance for any help or pointer in the right direction!